# Dynamic cron schedule based on storeconfig value

Tags: configuration, xml, cron

Is it possible to have my module cron schedule set in store config and can be updated by user?

I mean this node:

```
<schedule>
    <cron_expr>* * * * *</cron_expr>
</schedule>
```

Answer (score 1):

It is possible to define the cron schedule via system configuration.

**Example 1: `schedule/config_path`**

Magento looks up the cron expression in a given config path. The cron expression can now be defined directly in a corresponding admin panel text field. This requires a little technical understanding on the part of the user:

- [Aoe_Scheduler system.xml](https://github.com/AOEpeople/Aoe_Scheduler/blob/v1.3.1/app/code/community/Aoe/Scheduler/etc/system.xml#L40) (config field definition)
- [Aoe_Scheduler config.xml](https://github.com/AOEpeople/Aoe_Scheduler/blob/v1.3.1/app/code/community/Aoe/Scheduler/etc/config.xml#L141) (cron job definition)

**Example 2: `schedule/cron_expr`**

The cron expression is calculated individually using the admin panel input fields *frequency* and *time* in the backend model. The cron expression is then read from the database instead of the standard `config.xml` crontab definition. The user does not need to know about cron expression syntax:

- [Mage_Sitemap system.xml](https://github.com/bragento/magento-core/blob/1.9.2.3/app/code/core/Mage/Sitemap/etc/system.xml#L170) (config fields definition)
- [Mage_Sitemap config.xml](https://github.com/bragento/magento-core/blob/1.9.2.3/app/code/core/Mage/Sitemap/etc/config.xml#L102) (cron job definition, schedule omitted)
- [Mage_Sitemap backend model](https://github.com/bragento/magento-core/blob/1.9.2.3/app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Model/System/Config/Backend/Sitemap/Cron.php#L37) (cron expression calculation)